# Fisher Information: While calculating the expectation of score function, why do we integrate with dx?

Tags: statistics

Let $$S=\frac{d}{dy} \left[\log f(x|y)\right]$$ where $y$ is the parameter and $S$ is score function

Now in text books,

```
              Ey[S] = integrate (S*f(x|y)*dx)
```

While I think it should be

```
              Ey[S] = integrate (S*y*dy)
```

my reasoning goes like this, the expectation is defined to be the weighted mean of variable and its function at that point. Here the function is S and it depends on y so the expectation is the weighted mean run over all y's. 
To get a link of my problem visit

http://people.missouristate.edu/songfengzheng/Teaching/MTH541/Lecture%20notes/Fisher_info.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, when you write $E_y[S]$, it means that you fix the parameter of the distribution of X being equal to $y$ and then you calculate the expected value with this parameter. So you integrate with respect to the density of $X$ when its parameter is $y$, which is $f(x|y)$.

Comment: if that's the case then shouldn't it be d(f(x|y) instead of dx?

Comment: No, the *probability density function* is $f(x|y)$, so the *measure* you use to integrate is $dP_{X}(x)=f(x|y)dx$.